# Vectorization in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, variables, matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to create a vector of size 121x101 such that the ith column is made up of `V_t*e`, where `V_t = 1000*10^((i-1)/20)` and `e` is a 121 long column of ones.

Clearly `i` is to be varied from 1 to 101 million, but how would I apply that to a matrix without only yielding the final value in the results (applying this to every column without repeating commands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it looks like each row is the same. Thus, you can just calculate one row using [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) as

```
iRow = 1:101;
V_t = 1000*10.^((iRow-1)/20);
V_te = repmat(V_t,121,1);
```

If you want to have `e` be 1 in row 1, 2 in row 2, etc, you can use [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) to create two arrays of the same size as the output, which contain the values of `e` and `i` for every element `(i,j)` of the output

```
[ee,ii] = ndgrid(1:121,1:101);
V_te = 1000*10.^((i-1)/20) .* ee;
```

or you can use [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) to do the expansion of `e` and `i` for you

```
iRow = 1:101;
V_t = 1000*10.^((iRow-1)/20);
V_te = bsxfun(@times,V_t,(1:121)');
```

Comment: Yeah, each row is the same. That seems to have worked, thanks. For some reason when I tried computing V_t before it did not accept the i (now iRow) variable because it tried calculating a scalar. I thought some kind of piecewise function (.) was necessary, just not where. Thanks again.

Comment: @alan: You're welcome. If you use arrays in algebraic expressions, it's safest to always use `.` operators.